# Cannot Retrieve New Data in SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssms

I created a database with NBA player statistics just to practice SQL and SSRS.  I am new to working with stored procedures, but I created the following procedure that should (I think) allow me to specify the team and number of minutes.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE extrapstats
--Declare variables for the team and the amount of minutes to use in --calculations
    @team NCHAR OUTPUT,
    @minutes DECIMAL OUTPUT

AS 
BEGIN

SELECT p.Fname + ' ' + p.Lname AS Player_Name,
       p.Position,
       --Creates averages based on the number of minutes per game specified in @minutes
       (SUM(plg.PTS)/SUM(plg.MP))*@minutes AS PTS,
       (SUM(plg.TRB)/SUM(plg.MP))*@minutes AS TRB,
       (SUM(plg.AST)/SUM(plg.MP))*@minutes AS AST,
       (SUM(plg.BLK)/SUM(plg.MP))*@minutes AS BLK,
       (SUM(plg.STL)/SUM(plg.MP))*@minutes AS STL,     
       (SUM(plg.TOV)/SUM(plg.MP))*@minutes AS TOV,
       (SUM(plg.FT)/SUM(plg.MP))*@minutes AS FTs,
       SUM(plg.FT)/SUM(plg.FTA) AS FT_Percentage,
       (SUM(plg.FG)/SUM(plg.MP))*@minutes AS FGs,
       SUM(FG)/SUM(FGA) as Field_Percentage,
       (SUM(plg.[3P])/SUM(plg.MP))*@minutes AS Threes,
       SUM([3P])/SUM([3PA]) AS Three_Point_Percentage
FROM PlayerGameLog plg
--Joins the Players and PlayerGameLog tables
INNER JOIN Players p
ON p.PlayerID = plg.PlayerID
    AND TeamID = @team
GROUP BY p.Fname, p.Lname, p.Position, p.TeamID
ORDER BY PTS DESC

END;
```

I then tried to use the SP by executing the query below:

```
DECLARE @team NCHAR,
        @minutes DECIMAL

EXECUTE extrapstats @team = 'OKC', @minutes = 35
SELECT *
```

When I do that, I encounter this message:

```
Msg 263, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Must specify table to select from.
```

I've tried different variations of this, but nothing has worked.  I thought the SP specified the tables from which to select the data.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have a statement `SELECT *` dangling there. You didn't specify a table to select from. Hence the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring the stored procedure parameters with OUTPUT clause means the values will be returned by the stored procedure to the calling function. However you are using them as input parameters, please remove the OUTPUT clause from both input parameters and try.

Also remove the SELECT * in your execute statement, it is not required, the stored procedure will return the data as it has the select statement.

Comment: That was a newbie move on my part.  Thanks.